# Django blog post by authors

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am building a blog in django 3. I want to filter all posts by author and display the results in author page. I can't seem to figure what is wrong with my code. Please help. If i can get an explaination on what is wrong with my code, that will be appreciated.

**Views.py**

```
class AuthorPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'author_post.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author = self.request.user).order_by('created_on').reverse()

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(AuthorPostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['authorpost_list'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_slug       = models.SlugField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    body            = models.TextField()
    created_on      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    author          = models.ForeignKey(
                        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                        related_name = 'blog_posts',
                        )
    post_picture    = models.ImageField(
                        upload_to = 'post_picture', 
                        null = True, 
                        blank = True,
                        default='/media/post_picture/2.jpg',
                        )
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tags            = TaggableManager()
    categories      = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name = 'posts')

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Template**

```
{% for object in authorpost_list %}
    {{ object.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('author_post/', views.AuthorPostListView.as_view(), name = 'author_posts'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are over-riding the actual view you wanted with get context data, so you can remove the get context method and call in the template as

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can do

```
context['authorpost_list'] = Post.objects.filter(author = self.request.user).order_by('-created_on')
```

and call in template in the same way as you shown

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have tried that before and still did it again. It is not working. Any more tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output you are getting, any errors there

Comment: def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.order_by('created_on').reverse()

Comment: when i overide the get_queryset as above the template populates with list of all the post's titles. but i cant seem to filter them according to authors.

Comment: print(context['authorpost_list']), and see the result in the terminal, with context as I shown

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable